# Can I fake phone sensors data?

Tags: hardware, lg, sensors, auto-rotation

**Context :**

Most of my LG G3 sensors are broken following a water damage.

The main problem is the broken auto-rotation sensor that prevent me of taking photos in landscape mode.

I known [some applications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol&hl=fr) allow to manually set phone rotation to landscape but it is not what I am searching because it not working on the stock Camera application (witch use auto-rotation sensor to define the orientation of the phone).

Moreover I can not use other Camera application because of the bad photo quality (because of [LG closed source framework](https://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/37wqp3/anyone_interested_in_a_bounty_for_porting_the_lg/)).

---

**Question :**

Is that possible to fake data incoming from the auto-rotation sensor to make the phone think it is held horizontally ?
My phone is rooted, is that possible using a Terminal an application or anything else ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It may be possible, as it is possible for the emulator: https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator
I guess you could try to install the apk file from this project on your phone and then connect with the sensor tool

Comment: Thanks! I just tried unfortunately it is not working. Apk need to connect to emulator and sensor setting cannot be done in local.